# Append to start and end of first few lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed

What sed command would allow me to append one string to the end of every line, a different string to the start of the first line, and a different string to the end of the fifth line?

So far I have

```
    sed 's/$/<br>/' $FILE1 >> $FILE1_GETS_APPENDED_TO_THIS_FILE
```

to append a html break statement to the end of each line in the file1. I need to add a header statement around the first 5 lines though. Therefore, the start of the first line needs to have `<h3>` appended to it and the end of the fifth line needs `</h3>` appened to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's that easy:

```
sed 's/$/<br>/; 1 s/^/<h3>/; 5 s/$/<\/h3>/'
```

As you use `$` to match the end of the line, use `^` to match the start of the line.

Then, for each of your commands (such as `s`), you can specify a line number (or range) where it should apply.

Answer (score 2):

Add a number before a sed command to apply it only to that line. Add two numbers separated by a comma to specify a line number range. `$` stands for the last line. For more information, see “addresses” in your sed manual.

```
sed -e '1 s/^/<h3>/' -e '5 s/$/<\/h3>/' -e '6,$ s/$/<br>/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like awk for this kind of stuff:

```
awk 'NR==1{print "<h3>"};{print $0, "<br>"};NR==5{print "</h3>"}' file.htm
```

Comment: you can also use BEGIN and END to achieve the same effect.

Comment: You can leave printing of to the end: `NR==1 {$0="<h3>" $0} NR==5 {$0=$0 "</h3>"} 1`. `1` is true and executes the default block: `{ print $0 }`.

Comment: @sud03r: I'm not sure how BEGIN/END would help here. They execute at the beginning and end of the entire text stream.

Comment: @Porges yes you are right, i didn't understood the requirement correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "addresses" in `sed` manual. You can specify a line number to which a command should be applied:

```
sed '5s/$/Appended after fifth line/'
```